# Redirect ?catid=0&id= part of URL using Regex and .htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I want to replace:

```
https://www.domain.com/?catid=0&id=6330
```

By:

```
https://www.domain.com/artigos/6330
```

Using `.htaccess`

This is what I'm trying:

```
RewriteRule ^?catid=0&id=(.*)$ /artigos/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But is giving me a `500 internal server error`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you show us more relevant lines form your apache config? I.e. have you enabled mod_rewrite etc?

Comment: @neuhaus yes, I have enabled mod_rewrite and have other working redirects on this joomla site

Comment: Have you checked the error log? The "?" needs to be escaped. But it won't work like that. See my answer below.

Comment: @neuhaus thanks, I tried RewriteRule ^%{?catid=0&id=}(.*)$ /artigos/$1 [R=301,L] and RewriteRule ^{?catid=0&id=}(.*)$ /artigos/$1 [R=301,L]
but I still get the 404

Comment: Again, check the answer below. You need to use RewriteCond with %{QUERY_STRING}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't match against query strings in a RewriteRule directive. To match against query strings you need to use a RewriteCond.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /\?catid=0&id=([0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /artigost/%1? [NC,L,R]
```

Empty question mark at the end of the rewrite target is important, as it discards the old query strings.

Comment: Lol, almost there (just remove the t after artigos

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule):

> What is matched?
>
> In VirtualHost context, The Pattern will initially be matched against
>   the part of the URL after the hostname and port, and before the query
>   string (e.g. "/app1/index.html").
>
> In Directory and htaccess context, the Pattern will initially be
>   matched against the filesystem path, after removing the prefix that
>   led the server to the current RewriteRule (e.g. "app1/index.html" or
>   "index.html" depending on where the directives are defined).
>
> If you wish to match against the hostname, port, or query string, use
>   a RewriteCond with the %{HTTP_HOST}, %{SERVER_PORT}, or
>   %{QUERY_STRING} variables respectively.

The thing you are trying to match is part of the query string!